# How is read/write a text file possible in javascript if my text file is stored in server?

Tags: javascript, read-write

i am trying to read a file from the server and then write back to that same file again using javascript. Is it possible to read/write the text file using JSON,Javascript or Ajax.

Comment: You can use ajax to request the file from the server and then in the success callback you can process the file contents

Comment: Why write to a text file and not a database? Think about what will happen when multiple people are running the code, you'll end up locking the file.

Comment: i am using pure client side languages only so database would never come into picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is client-side language, so it don't have access to server. To do it you have to use AJAX and some server-side language, eg. PHP to handle requests.

Comment: ya i thought of it but since i was not allowed to use PHP i tried using SHELL instead and it worked thanks..

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to edit server sided files using pure Javascript, imagine the security issues :)

What you could do is to use a server sided language, like PHP or ASP, and send an ajax request to the server containing the information you want to write.

Answer (score 2):

You can read a file with javascript via an AJAX call. 
You cannot save a file with javaScript.
You will need a server side language like PHP.

You can use:
step 1) jquery to load a file: http://api.jquery.com/load/
step 2) jquery to send the modified text to the .php : script http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
step 2.1) save the data in php : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJson("/main.txt",function(jsonObject){

// your logic;

})
```